# How can I make my html slideshow responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried making my slideshow responsive using this line of code

```
<img src="nature.jpg" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
```

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

But it made no difference at all. I uploaded my site here: https://acaschoolgpa.000webhostapp.com/

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>ACA NHS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="favico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="favico/favicon-192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="favico/favicon-160.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favico/favicon-96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="favico/favicon-64.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favico/favicon-32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favico/favicon-16.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favico/favicon-57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="favico/favicon-114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="favico/favicon-72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="favico/favicon-144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="favico/favicon-60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="favico/favicon-120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="favico/favicon-76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="favico/favicon-152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="favico/favicon-180.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="favico/favicon-144.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-config" content="favico/browserconfig.xml">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        </head>
<header>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <img src="logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="HTML tag">
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="boyshome.html">Boys Campus</a></li>
          <li><a href="girlshome.html">Girls Campus</a></li>
          <li><a href="calculator.html">GPA Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p class="bluebackground">&emsp;</p>
    <br>
    <div class="slideshow-container" class="responsive">

        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/foodtopeopleschool.jpg')"class="responsive">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 5</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/onground.jpg')" class="responsive">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/givingwater.jpg')" class="responsive">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 5</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/holdingcamera.jpg')" class="responsive">
            <div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides fade" style="--background-image: url('homepagepictures/studentsgroup.jpg')" class="responsive">
            <div class="numbertext">5 / 5</div>
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
    </div>


    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
    <h1 class="Welcome">WELCOME TO THE ACA NHS WEBSITE!</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    </center>
    <h2 class="message">Our Message</h2>
    <p id="messagetext" align="justify">"Long before National Honor Society was available in the American Creativity Academy, students sought after an opportunity to create, inspire, and open the doors for creativity. With a heritage of respect to individuality and personal interest, the National Honor Society offered a platform for creation and student ingenuity. Today, the dream of a boy who grew up between the blue walls of ACA turned into reality: he can finally create and enjoy creation for a respected audience!</p>
    <p id="messagetext" align="justify">The National Honor Society is a community by students within the campus that works towards creating a better school and local environment. We believe that every act of kindness, no matter how insignificant it may seem, has a drastic impact on a person and starts a ripple of kind-hearted acts among the people. The NHS creates opportunities for its members in volunteering within and off the campus and raising awareness for global issues, which makes them more productive, responsible and engaged citizens. We try to make a difference by inspiring and supporting the people around us whenever we can.</p>
    <p id="messagetext" align="justify">The NHS team is more than all of its members; although the impact of one person is limited, working as a team allows us to achieve our goal and leave behind a great mark. We envision a kinder society where people are keen on helping others, and will work until that vision is achieved."</p>
    <p id="messagetext" align="justify">- By the NHS Team</p>
    <footer class="footer-distributed">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <h3>NHS<span>ACA</span></h3>
            <p class="footer-links">Boys Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/nhsb.aca/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 nhsb.aca</a>&emsp;
                 |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:nhsb.aca@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                nhsb.aca@gmail.com</a>
            </p>
            <p class="footer-links">Girls Campus:</p>
            <p class="footer-links">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aca.nhs/"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                 aca.nhs</a>&emsp;
                  |&emsp;
                 <a href="mailto:acanational.hs@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                acanational.hs@gmail.com</a>
            </p>
            <br>
            <p class="footer-company-name">© Mohammad al Nusif</p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-center">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/B3vW2nPkNewZUyxW9"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Boys Campus map</p></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/uKS7qgy5P6F8csRK7"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Girls Campus map</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span>Boys Campus:</span>
                Advisor's Email - sali.alkhuraishi@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's Email - bahaabed2003@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's Email - azoibi17@gmail.com<br>
                <br>
                <span>Girls Campus:</span>
                Advisor's Email - nicole.depew@aca.edu.kw<br>
                President's Email - kayanalghanim@gmail.com<br>
                Vice President's Email - skkh03@gmail.com <br>
                <br>
            <div class="footer-icons">
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}

.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}




/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F0E68C;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFD750;
}
.Welcome {  
    font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif; 
    font-size: 62px; 
    font-weight: 800; 
    line-height: 45px; 
    margin: 0 0 24px; 
    text-align: center; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.message {
    font-family: "Great Vibes";
    font-size: 62px; 
    font-weight: 600; 
}

.example_e {
    border: none;
    width: 759px;
    background: #6495ED;
    color: Yellow !important;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.example_e:hover {
    color: #404040 !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    background: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.girls-message{
    color: #F0E68C
}

.mySlides {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;

    background-image: var(--background-image);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.mySlides > .numbertext {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.bluebackground{
    background-color: #4169E1;
    margin:0;
}
#messagetext{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px
}

@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');




/* The footer is fixed to the bottom of the page */

footer{
    bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-height:800px){
    footer { position: static; }
}


.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #2c292f;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: bold 16px sans-serif;
    padding: 50px 50px 60px 50px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 30%;
}

.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}

/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed .footer-left img{
    width: 30%;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  #e0ac1c;
}

/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Footer Center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
}


.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #e0ac1c;
    text-decoration: none;;
}


/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 30%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}



@media (max-width: 880px) {

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    margin-left: 0;
}

}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cookie';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Cookie-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/cookie/v12/syky-y18lb0tSbf9kgqS.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

#container {
    text-align: center;
}
a, figure {
    display: inline-block;
}
figcaption {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #bb3333;
}
figure {
    padding: 5px;
}
img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}
img {
    transition: transform 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.2s;
}

.middlecent{
    justify-content: center;
}
    
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This is my javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
var timeGap = 5000; 
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

setInterval(function() {
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  slideIndex++
}, timeGap)
```

My site looks really weird on mobile but looks great on pc. Mostly because of the slideshow

Comment: First problem: `.slideshow-container` has `min-width: 1000px;`. Are you debugging this in the browser tools using "inspect element"? If not, press F12 and check the inspector tab.

Comment: Nope I am not. I'm kinda new to html and I didnt change it since it worked great on my pc. I thought that it would transfer to all devices. But I was mistaken

Comment: <div class="slideshow-container" class="responsive"> is also not valid html. To have multiple classes on one element, it should be written as <div class="slideshow-container responsive">

Comment: Oh I had no idea. But I tried it and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly remove your min-width: 1000px; in your slideshow-container. Never ever specify min-width more than 400px, if you need your site to be responsive.
Secondly, always adjust your container not the image width or height. Try not to go over the image height as it looks stretched. Try to use background-size: 100% 100%; to display the whole image.

```css
.slideshow-container {
  min-width: unset;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.mySlides {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Thirdly, do not specify class attribute two times on a single element. Use same attribute and add multiple classes in that.
class="slideshow-container responsive"